# how draw ring with transparent internal background (corona sdk)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

how draw the ring with transparent internal background (corona sdk). dipslay.newCircle will draw only a circle but not the ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
local circle = display.newCircle (100,100,200)
circle:setFillColor(0,0,0,0) --This will set the fill color to transparent
circle.strokeWidth = 3 --This is the width of the outline of the circle
circle:setStrokeColor(255,0,0) --This is the color of the outline
```

Comment: The APIs for this have changed in newer releases of Corona SDK. Visit https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ShapeObject/stroke.html